# How a user can cancel/back option, when he is in login screen?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

[image: SF Login Screen]

I dont see a cancel/back option, in the login screen. If the user wishes to that, how can we provide the same?

Thanks,
SKG.

Comment: what do you expect with the cancel/back option ? only for apps which has public content it makes sense to have that so that you can go back to your start / home / previous navigation point. but for apps which is purely based on private content accessible only for logged in users, no point in having a cancel / back option.

Comment: Vamshi, MyApp SDFC as an optional component, for some reason the user forgot the login info, or doesn't want to login currently,  s/he needs to get back to the main app. One way is to implement my prop view controller. Is there a way to achieve the same in default provided by SF.

Answer (score 1):

If your app requires the user authenticate to Salesforce, then I agree with Vamsi - it makes no sense to put a cancel or back button on this screen because there's nothing else to do and nowhere else to go until the user authenticates.

Instead, if your app has SFDC as an optional component, then you can use any method you like to dismiss the login screen. It will depend on how you showed the login screen in the first place - you could dismiss a modal view controller, or pop to a previous view controller in the navigation stack, or remove a child view controller.

Comment: Sorry for not providing detailed info. MyAPP uses SFDC as on optional component. As you noted I can  dismiss the login screen, but todo that I need a user input (cancel/back button) to trigger the dismiss. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could display the login screen in a `UINavigationController` and add your own bar button items for any actions you want to present.